# How streaming service like youtube or twitch measure the client's network max speed?

Tags: javascript, networking, youtube, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

To service best video quaility on client's environment, How streaming services(like youtube or twich) measure client's network bandwidth/max speed?

I think 2 ways.

1. server send the many data over the network bandwidth through the websocket, and then check client check how many byte got from server for some seconds.
2. server start default video streaming and client measure the network speed in above.

In first, the data for checking network speed sent by server take server-client network bandwidth and that will make delay for video streaming.
In second way, if server video streaming data is not enough, slow network speed will be measured.

what is best way for that? thanks.

Comment: Method #2 is by far the most common.

Comment: @szatmary thanks to your reply, but In second way, how to detect network speed that was changed faster then past?

Comment: Network speed calculation is performed continually. All bytes the the video download are times for the entire duration of playback.

Comment: @szatmary Thanks to your reply! :)
I am confused.. if my server-client network full bandwidth is 100 and My video stream start with low quality that will be spend 10 bandwidth per second, Now Network speed will be calculated 10 per second, isn't it? It means I can't catch the chance to up my video quality. am I wrong? please give me your advice. thanks.

Comment: No. Video quality a is irrelevant. It’s just a file. 1MB download in 1 second is the same as 2MB downloaded in 2 seconds.